# How to change Windows 10 login screen inactivity timeout?

Tags: authentication, windows-10, credential-providers

We are developing some MFA (multi-factor authentication) support on Windows. After entering the user password it will have other challenge like email/phone calls.

But on Windows 10 we found that the login screen (not remote) will close after 30s of inactivity. In some cases the email/phone challenge may take more than 30s, and logon screen being closed will stop the email/phone wait.

Is there any way, like registry, to change the Windows 10 logon timeout value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a customer with paid MS support account.

The registry controlling the login screen timeout is:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
DWORD Value: IdleTimeOut
Unit: msec
```

Comment: Worked for me - but instead of IdleTimeOut - The key is called "IdleTime"

Comment: @redestructa It is "IdleTimeOut" for me. I think "IdleTime" is the time you idled at the previous logon. It changes every time after you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

## Another way to do it

Because the registry key wasn't here and adding it didn't work.

My windows versions (for info):

```bsh
(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion").ReleaseId
#1803
```

```bsh
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object caption, version
#caption                  version
#-------                  -------
#Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.17134
```

---

#### 1. Get Your Scheme or use 'SCHEME_CURRENT' alias

Check your current power scheme:

```bsh
powercfg.exe /LIST
#Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
#-----------------------------------
#Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
#Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
#Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

Get your current scheme alias:

```bsh
(powercfg.exe /QUERY ((powercfg.exe /GETACTIVESCHEME) -replace '.* ([0-9a-f-]{36}) .*', '$1'))|Select-String -Pattern "^  GUID Alias"
#GUID Alias: SCHEME_BALANCED
```

#### 2. Set lock timeout AC or DC

Use `/SETACVALUEINDEX` when you are **not** on battery

Use `/SETDCVALUEINDEX` when on battery

The value is in seconds, so here `1200s = 60s * 20` i.e. 20minutes

```bsh
powercfg.exe /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEOCONLOCK 1200
```